# Database connection leak in Spring Boot with SseEmitter

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I have a problem with a database connection pool in Spring Boot 2, where connections are not returned to the pool even though they are neatly wrapped in `@Transactional`.

Upon opening the home page, I run a query and then open an SSE stream:

```
@GetMapping("")
public SseEmitter home() {
  derpService.derp();
  return obs.subscribeSse();
}
```

The `derp()` call looks like this:

```
@Transactional
void derp() {
    derpRepository.derp();
}
```

Which leads to:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT 'derp'", nativeQuery = true)
void derp();
```

As long as the SSE stream is open, the connection from the `derp()` call is not released. This can easily be shown by opening `http://localhost:8088` in six tabs: the sixth tab will not load because all connections are in use.

I made a minimal example on https://github.com/Oduig/connectionleak.
Is this a bug in Spring, or am I using `SseEmitter`/`@Transactional` in the wrong way?

Comment: The open EntityManager in view pattern is [enabled by default in Spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-in-web-environment). Have you disabled it?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Wow, that fixes it! I looked for the problem for hours, as I wasn't aware of what this property did. If you provide an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I am glad I found this, albeit after losing a week to this issue.  I have a  ControllerAdvice and ModelAttribute that queries the DB to get my custom  user object and supply it to the controller methods (since otherwise only the basic Spring principal/user object is available.)  It seems that the associated connection was being held for as long as the SseEmitter was alive, quickly extinguishing the db connection pool.  IMHO a query that executes and completes inside a ModelAttribute method in a ControllerAdvice shouldn't keep a connection open for as long as the SseEmitter is alive!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the comment by @Andy Wilkinson:

Closing entities by default is the solution.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-in-web-environment

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue when we introduced SSE streams into our 6 year old sprig boot app.  When I disabled open-in-view, our app started to throw errors due to lazy loaded collections not being loaded due to missing session.  We're going to go and start to clean these errors up but to get things working immediately, I set the following properties in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

I hope this will help someone facing the same issue trying to get SSE to play nice with the rest of your spring boot controllers.