# Hikari pool connection not available when SseEmiter is refreshed multiple times by front-end

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

Im using SseEmiter in Spring Boot application to send notifications to Frontend. Everything works fine, the client receives the initial notification and every other notification sent. Тhe problem occurs when page is refreshed 10 or more times. The hickari pool gets filled up and throw a timeout exception. How can I prevent this behavior and clear the old unused connections in the pool?

Controller class

```
@RestController
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping("/notifications")
public class NotificationsController {

    private final NotificationsService notificationsService;
    public NotificationsController(NotificationsService notificationsService) {
        this.notificationsService = notificationsService;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter subscribe() {
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        notificationsService.registerEmitter(sseEmitter);
        return sseEmitter;
    }
```

Emitter handal in Service

```
private final Map<String, User> emitters = new HashMap<>();

public void registerEmitter(SseEmitter sseEmitter) {
     sendInitEvent(sseEmitter);
     addToEmittersMap(sseEmitter);
}

private void sendInitEvent(SseEmitter sseEmitter) {
    try {
        sseEmitter.send(listNotifications());
        logger.info("Initial event to emitter sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}

private void addToEmittersMap(SseEmitter sseEmitter) {
    User user = new User(authService.getUserId(),
            authService.getGins().stream()
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .toList(),
            sseEmitter);
    emitters.remove(authService.getUserId());
    emitters.put(authService.getUserId(), user);
    logger.info("Emitter added");
}

@Modifying
@Transactional
public List<NotificationsView> listNotifications() {
    List<NotificationsHistory> events = notificationsRepository.getByGinInAndTsBetween(
            authService.getGins().stream()
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toList(),
            Instant.now().minus(60, ChronoUnit.MINUTES),
            Instant.now());
    return notificationsMapper.toDtos(events);
}
```

Repository class

```
 @Repository
 public interface NotificationsRepository extends JpaRepository<NotificationsHistory, Integer> {
 }
```

Update on 09.03.2023

Partialy the problem was solved by changing the upper class so the old SseEmitter is set to "complete" but in one point (30 mins) of work same exception appears.

Change in code
Solution

```
private void addToEmittersMap(SseEmitter sseEmitter) {
User user = new User(authService.getUserId(),
        authService.getGins().stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .toList(),
        sseEmitter);
if(emitters.containsKey(authService.getUserId())){
     emitters.get(authService.getUserId()).emitter().complete();
     logger.info("Old connection completed");
}
emitters.put(authService.getUserId(), user);
logger.info("Emitter added");
```

}

Error message

> SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2023-03-08T14:11:13.270+02:00 ERROR
> 139580 --- [nio-8189-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
> : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after
> 30000ms. 2023-03-08T14:11:13.274+02:00 ERROR 139580 ---
> [nio-8189-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed:
> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction] with root cause
>
> java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is
> not available, request timed out after 30000ms.   at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)
> ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181)
> ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146)
> ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
> ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]  at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:137)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:152)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
> ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
> ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
> ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
> ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
> ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
> ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> com.lsbo.notifications.notificaations.service.NotificationsService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.registerEmitter()
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.lsbo.notifications.notificaations.api.NotificationsController.subscribe(NotificationsController.java:27)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
> ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]  at
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:399)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:297)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:79)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:125)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:145)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:280)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
> ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
> ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Comment: First of all, I would check whether any emitters actually get cleared from the map when a new one is registered for a user.
Second, the error you're getting has to do with database connections, but I don't see anything relating to a database call in your provided code. Please provide a sample of this.

Comment: I have editted the post and added the information you requested. Emitters are removed from emmiters map in addToEmittersMap() method. DB call is made every time a new SseEmiter is created to provide notifications stored in DB for period of 60 minutes.

Comment: Your `@Transactional` doesn't do anything as it is an internal method call. Hence you are leaking connections.

Comment: That was not the case. I removed the annotations, they were needed before, because the logic was a bit different in that method. But even when I comment the part that make repository calls the problem appears again. 
Тhe problem generation process is as follows:
1. Launch the application
2. Opening a connection through postman with Authorization Bearer Token
3. Close and open the connection repeatedly (10x times).
After which I get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams that the problem was generated because open-in-view option in spring configuration was set to true. It has to be set to false.
I found the answer here:
[Database connection leak in Spring Boot with SseEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071931/database-connection-leak-in-spring-boot-with-sseemitter)

Answer (score 0):

Setting *open-in-view* to *false* could resolve the issue.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
```

I was wondering ***why*** though and [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view) helped me understand why.

This setting is *true* by default, which enables Spring to seamlessly take care of the lazy loaded properties of entities. The developer doesn't need to watch out for how these properties are loaded, which facilitates the development. To make this possible, [Spring binds a Hibernate Session to the thread for the entire processing of the request](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html), when the request flow includes connecting to the DB. Once the connection is taken from the pool, it remains assigned to the request scope and it's never released to the pool until after the request completes. SSE usually implies long-running requests and when some of them require DB connections, the connection pool may get exhausted.

Setting *open-in-view* to *false* changes this behaviour as the DB connection is released to the pool as soon as the DB call completes. There shouldn't be any issues after changing this setting if you don't declare any lazy associations. If there are lazy associations, you have to take care of the lazy loading, e.g. with [@EntityGraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.html) on some repository methods.